# Change the name of my user drive?

Tags: hard-drive, high-sierra

I used to have two drives on my machine, Fast and Big. I replaced Big with Bigger. Now there are a number of pointers in various apps that still point to Big.

Is there a way to rename my new drive to be Big? It's my user drive, so it won't let me do it in the obvious way using Get Info.

Comment: Have you tried opening the Disk Utility, right clicking on the name and selecting Rename?

Comment: I am guessing you have tried simply clicking on the desktop icon and pressing the enter key to rename?

Comment: I have tried both of these, the name is "locked" in both cases and will not change.

Comment: Try it from Recovery.